# Get result from cancelled asyncio.gather tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I need to get some values from an async generator concurrently, and I also need to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` correctly so that whenever the application is quit I have a chance to write to disk whatever was retrieved at the moment of the exception. I came up with the following code:

```
import asyncio


async def some_task():
    try:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
        await asyncio.sleep(10000)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass


async def run_tasks():
    async def _task(gen):
        return [value async for value in gen]

    try:
        result = await asyncio.gather(_task(some_task()))
        return result
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # Do something here to get the result from the gathered tasks
        ...


async def amain():
    value = await run_tasks()
    print("Returned", value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

I tried using `asyncio.shield` but `asyncio.gather` still throws an exception instead of returning the value from `_task`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception - be it KeyboardInterrupt or another, will break the functions at the point they occur, and `return` statements won't be reached. The same takes place for list comprehensions or other expressions: the inner `for` loop will be cancelled.

But just by unfolding the comprehension in a multi-line `for` statement, and adding elements one at a time, one gets full control of the flow with try/except blocks, with no other changes needed.

Here, I write an alterantive path with `except BaseException:`  (just `Exception` won't catch a  KeybordInterrupt)-  but you can even have a single code path for both exceptions ocurring and normal flow by using the `finally` clause instead.

(Also, when handling an exception you don´t care about, but just want to perform some action when it occurs, it is important to re-raise it, so code further in the call stack can know what took place)

```
...
import asyncio

async def some_task():
    try:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
        await asyncio.sleep(10000)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass

async def run_tasks():
    results = []
    async def _task(gen, results):
        # a nested funciton could just use the "results" from the outer scope. parameter included so it can be used in not-nested functions
        async for item in gen:
            results.append(item)

    try:
        await asyncio.gather(_task(some_task(), results))
        return results
    except BaseException:
        # Do this here to get the result from the gathered tasks
        print(f"Something stopped the task. Partial results: {results}")
        raise
        ...
    return results

async def amain():
    try:
        value = await run_tasks()
    finally:
        print("Returned", global_results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

Comment: I actually tried using a queue for this same purpose, so every concurrent task can communicate to the parent task the result as soon as it sees it. In any case I also came up with a solution by adding a `loop.add_signal_handler` to capture SIGINT and just cancelling the tasks, so gather never throws, but I'm not sure how that works, is a subsequent call to `loop.add_signal_handler` going to override the last handler?

Comment: loop.add_signal_handler callbacks replace the last added handler for the same signal: if other code is using the same approach, you can be caught short-handed.
It is possible to write your hander in a colaborative way, if you keep track of other handlers already installed and call then explicitly in your handler - but that does not ensure other players do the same.

Actualy: `try..finally` is both a lot easier and some 2 orders of magnitude more "mundane" code for this kind of thing.

Comment: Using queues would be a nice idea - for sure.

Comment: I agree, I think letting it throw and catch it "naturally" is a better approach

Comment: In any case, for the sake of the op: the problem was not that the task was being cancelled, but rather that a `KeyboardInterrupt` was being thrown from `asyncio.gather` while `asyncio.run` cancels the tasks and also that `gather` does not set the result when that happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291518/2625090